# Como resolver o erro ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable no rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em rails e o seguinte erro aparece no meu banco na hora que tento realizar um rake db:migrate. Já tentei dar um drop no banco e um create em sequencia, entretanto o mesmo erro acontece. O curioso é que o mesmo estava funcionando normalmente e não houve nenhuma alteração no modulo "products" da aplicação.

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERRO:  relação "products" não existe
>   LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"products"'::regclass
>                                          ^
>   :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
>                       pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, >a.atttypmod
>                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
>                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
>               WHERE a.attrelid = '"products"'::regclass
>                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
>               ORDER BY a.attnum

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.references :type
      t.string :mark
      t.string :model
      t.string :engine
      t.text :description
      t.string :barcode
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :products, :type_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Poste o código da migration que está quebrando.

Comment: Provavelmente algum migration que está rodando antes dessa que cria a tabela de produtos está fazendo referencia a tabela, verifique as migrations anteriores.

Comment: Alex,consegui achar o problema. Estou testando o Active Admin e acredito que a relação deva ser feita na interface de admin tb. Comentei a interface que estava editando e a migração foi feita. Problema resolvido. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Alex,consegui achar o problema. Estou testando o Active Admin e acredito que a relação deva ser feita na interface de admin tb. Comentei a interface que estava editando e a migração foi feita. Problema resolvido. Obrigado